# Get host from cookie

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am building and extension with Firefox's Addon SDK (v1.9).

My application is supposed to remove cookies as they are added (or changed) based on a database of matching URIs.

I accomplish this task by adding an observer to 'cookie-changed' and implementing [nsICookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICookie) to identify matching cookies and [nsICookieManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICookieManager) to remove the cookie if a match is found.

**Problem**

I need know what website (URL) each cookie was added / changed from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, by the time the cookie manager sends the `cookie-changed` notification that information is already lost - the cookie manager only knows which host the cookie is added for (and it might not be the host of the page setting the cookie if `domain` parameter was used). It might even be that there was no URL in the first place, e.g. if the cookie is set by an extension.

What you could do is register an observer for the `http-on-examine-response` notification. You can look at the `Set-Cookie` header of the channel as well as the channel URL so when `cookie-changed` notification is sent later you will know which website is responsible. Something like this:

```js
var observer = require("observer-service");
observer.add("http-on-examine-response", function(subject, data)
{
  subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
  var cookieNames = [];

  // There can be more than one Set-Cookie header, cannot use getResponseHeader
  subject.visitResponseHeaders(function(header, value)
  {
    if (header.toLowerCase() == "set-cookie")
    {
      var match = /^([^\s=]+)=/.exec(value);
      if (match)
        cookieNames.push(match[1]);
    }
  });

  if (cookieNames.length)
  {
    var url = channel.URI.spec;

    // Remember that this url set the cookies or just clear the header
    if (!isAllowedToSetCookies(url, cookieNames))
      channel.setResponseHeader("Set-Cookie", "", false);
  }
});
```

*Note*: This code hasn't been tested.

Documentation: [observer notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests), [nsIHttpChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHttpChannel)

Comment: I use your code to modify Content Security Policy. After I called `setResponseHeader` I see in dev tools old value of header. Is there a way to be sure it works?

Comment: @nilfalse: Dev tools also use the `http-on-examine-response` notification to inspect the data - if they get their turn earlier than your extension they will show the original value. So the only certain way to know things work is looking at whether the header change causes any browser behavior changes. Mind you, I'm not sure how CSP is implemented internally - it might very well be using the `http-on-examine-response` notification, that would mean that you are modifying the header too late.